# Can I reuse driver instances when running Cucumber scenarios in parallel?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have a Cucumber TestNG test written that runs several tests in parallel. Currently I create the driver per scenario and my Hooks class looks like the following.

```
public class Hooks {


    private TestContext testContext;

    @Inject
    public Hooks(TestContext testContext) {
        this.testContext = testContext;
    }

    @Before
    public void initializeTestContext(final Scenario scenario) {
        this.testContext.initializeContext();
    }


    @After
    public void after(final Scenario scenario) {
        LOG.debug("Executing After Hook");
        if (shouldScreenshot(scenario)) {
            embedScreenshotToReport(scenario);
        }
        this.testContext.destroyContext();
    }

    @Before("@skip_scenario")
    public void skipScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        LOG.info("Skipping scenario: {}", scenario.getName());
        Assume.assumeTrue(false);
    }

    private boolean shouldScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
        return scenario.isFailed() && Screenshot.isRequired();
    }

    private void embedScreenshotToReport(Scenario scenario) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) testContext.getWebDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
}
```

My TestsContext class looks like the following.

```
@ScenarioScoped
public class TestContext extends WebUITest {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER_NAME = "default";

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return this.webDriver;
    }

    public void initializeContext() {
        System.out.println("DEBUGGING Test Context: driver created");
        this.webDriver = initializeDriver(URL.getTestHostURL(), DEFAULT_DRIVER_NAME);
    }

    public void destroyContext() {
        System.out.println("destory method called");
    }
}
```

My Runner class with TestNG looks like the following.

```
    glue = {"com.cucumber.test.glue.hook",
                "com.cucumber.test.glue.stepdef" },
        features = "features/MyFeature.feature",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:build/brazil-cucumber-tests/cucumber-pretty"},
        strict = true)

public class ParallelRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

I was thinking of reusing the same driver instance across parallel tests but is that possible? If so, how can I instantiate the driver? Cucumber doesn't seem to have a beforeAll kind of method and when I use beforeAll of testNG in Hooks class, it doesn't seem to get called. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing driver session across multiple thread doesn't makes sense. Instead reusing driver session between test/scenarios within same thread is possible. For that you need to update your code to use thread local driver instance.

Simplest way is to use [qaf-cucumber](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_cucumber.html) with [property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html)  `selenium.singletone = 1`. This stetting will reuse driver session for tests methods/scenarios running in same thread. If you change your mind and want to use new session for each scenario set  `selenium.singletone=Methods`

Anywhere you want driver object, you can get from testbase:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver();
```

your code may look like below:

```
public class Hooks {


    private TestContext testContext;

    @Inject
    public Hooks(TestContext testContext) {
        this.testContext = testContext;
    }

    @After
    public void after(final Scenario scenario) {
        LOG.debug("Executing After Hook");
        if (shouldScreenshot(scenario)) {
            embedScreenshotToReport(scenario);
        }
        this.testContext.destroyContext();
    }

    @Before("@skip_scenario")
    public void skipScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        LOG.info("Skipping scenario: {}", scenario.getName());
        Assume.assumeTrue(false);
    }

    private boolean shouldScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
        return scenario.isFailed() && Screenshot.isRequired();
    }

    private void embedScreenshotToReport(Scenario scenario) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
}

@ScenarioScoped
public class TestContext extends WebUITest {
//nothing to do for driver management!....
//just set driver.name property
//code below is only for compatibility
    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver();
    }
    public void destroyContext() {
        System.out.println("destory method called");
    }
}
```

You can take benefit of other features of [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io) like

- [listeners](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html)
- External [data-providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#in-built-data-providers)
- [Locator repository](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locator_repository.html)
- [Wait/Assertion/verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) with auto screenshot
- pure [TestNG BDD implementation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html#factory-class)